# NextJS getServerSideProps pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, supabase

I am using NextJS and Supabase for database. I am not sure how to use pagination here. Because the solution I am looking is passing query to the API. I cant do that because I am directly fetching it from database. What is the solution for me here?

```js
import { supabase } from "../lib/supabase";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function Cars({ data, count, page }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((carsdata) => (
        <ul key={carsdata.id}>
          <li>{carsdata.name}</li>
        </ul>
      ))}

      <button onClick={() => router.push(`/Cars?page=${page - 1}`)}>
        Prev
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => router.push(`/Cars?page=${page + 1}`)}>
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ query: { page = 1 } }) {
  const { data, count } = await supabase
    .from("cars")
    .select("*", { count: "exact" })
    .order("id", { ascending: true })
    .range(0, 9)
  return {
    props: {
      data: data,
      count: count,
      page: parseInt(page),
    },
  };
}
```

The solution is passing query to the API in `getServerSideProps` like this

```
const res = await fetch(`${API}/start=${start}`);
const data = await res.json()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do the pagination from the client since `getServerSideProps` execute when you refresh your page.

Comment: It is ok for a first render to use getServerSideProps but you have to handle the further pagination from client side, yes.

Comment: @gazdagergo Yes, that's true.

Comment: @AlenVlahovljak Could you point me in the direction how can I do that?

Comment: @kelly Check out [this](https://vpilip.com/how-build-simple-pagination-in-nextjs/)

Answer (score 1):

You can have server-side pagination with SSR, despite the comments in the previous answer.
You will have to load the page with the query that includes the page number like you already do in your `getServerSideProps`
And to get the right objects from the Database you will have to convert it to your `range()` function arguments.

For example, if your page counting starts from 1, you could get the right items from DB like this:

```
const pageSize = 10;

export async function getServerSideProps({ query: { page = 1 } }) {
  const pageIndex = parseInt(page);
  const rangeStart = (pageIndex - 1) * pageSize;
  const rangeEnd = rangeStart + pageSize;

  const { data, count } = await supabase
    .from("cars")
    .select("*", { count: "exact" })
    .order("id", { ascending: true })
    .range(rangeStart, rangeEnd)
  return {
    props: {
      data: data,
      count: count,
      page: pageIndex,
    },
  };
}
```

Now by fetching your page (let's assume your page route is `/products/cars`) with `page` query param you can get pages of cars: `/products/cars?page=2`

Here is an article that does something similar (not mine): https://ellismin.com/2020/05/next-pagination/

Comment: I'm afraid this code won't do it - the serverside props won't be adjusted unless you refresh, tried i this way. I wish it worked but it doesn't. The provided link works because it's hitting an external API after the page is loaded, which may not be what OP wants.